# Assigning sentiment to each tweet - Twitter trend

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, natural-language-processing

Below assignment is taken from [here](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/fa12/projects/trends/trends.html).

> **Introduction**
>
> In this project, you will develop a geographic visualization of
>   twitter data across the USA. You will need to use dictionaries, lists,
>   and data abstraction techniques to create a modular program. Below is
>   `phase 1` of this project.
>
> ***Phase 1: The Feelings in Tweets***
>
> In this phase, you will create an abstract data type for tweets, split the text of a tweet into words, and calculate the amount of
>   positive or negative feeling in a tweet.
>
> ***Tweets***
>
> **First**, you will **implement an abstract data type** for Tweets. The constructor `make_tweet` is defined at the top of `trends.py`.
>   `make_tweet` returns a python dictionary with the following entries:
>
> ```
>   text:      a string, the text of the tweet, all in lowercase
>   time:      a datetime object, when the tweet was posted
>   latitude:  a floating-point number, the latitude of the tweet's location
>   longitude: a floating-point number, the longitude of the tweet's location
> ```
>
> **Problem 1** (1 pt). **Implement** the `tweet_words` and `tweet_time` selectors. Call `extract_words` to list the words in the
>   text of a tweet.
>
> **Problem 2** (1 pt). **Implement** the `tweet_location` selector, which returns a position. Positions are another abstract data type,
>   defined at the top of `geo.py`. Make sure that you understand how to
>   manipulate positions; they play an important role in this project.
>
> > When you complete problems 1 and 2, the `doctest` for `make_tweet` should pass.
>
> ```
> python3 trends.py -t make_tweet
> ```
>
> **Problem 3** (1 pt). **Improve** the `extract_words` function as follows: Assume that a word is any consecutive substring of text that
>   consists only of ASCII letters. The string `ascii_letters` in the string
>   module contains all letters in the ASCII character set. The
>   `extract_words` function should list all such words in order and nothing
>   else.
>
> When you complete this problem, the `doctest` for extract_words should pass.
>
> ```
> python3 trends.py -t extract_words
> ```
>
> **Problem 4** (1 pt). **Implement** the **sentiment abstract data type**, which represents a sentiment value that may or may not exist.
>   The constructor `make_sentiment` takes either a numeric value within the
>   interval -1 to 1, or None to indicate that the value does not exist.
>   Implement the selectors `has_sentiment` and `sentiment_value` as well. You
>   may use any representation you choose, but the rest of your program
>   should not depend on this representation.
>
> When you complete this problem, the doctests for `make_sentiment` and `get_word_sentiment` should pass. You can also call the `print_sentiment`
>   function to print the sentiment values of all sentiment-carrying words
>   in a line of text.
>
> ```
> python3 trends.py -t make_sentiment
> python3 trends.py -t get_word_sentiment
> python3 trends.py -p computer science is my favorite!
> python3 trends.py -p life without lambda: awful or awesome?
> ```
>
> **Problem 5** (1 pt). **Implement** `analyze_tweet_sentiment`, which takes a tweet (of the abstract data type) and returns a sentiment.
>   Read the docstrings for `get_word_sentiment` and `analyze_tweet_sentiment`
>   to understand how the two functions interact. Your implementation
>   should not depend on the representation of a sentiment!.
>
> When you complete this problem, the doctests for `analyze_tweet_sentiment` should pass.
>
> ```
> python3 trends.py -t analyze_tweet_sentiment
> ```

Below is the solution for phase 1:

```python
from data import word_sentiments, load_tweets
from datetime import datetime
from doctest import run_docstring_examples
from geo import us_states, geo_distance, make_position, longitude, latitude
from maps import draw_state, draw_name, draw_dot, wait, message
from string import ascii_letters
from ucb import main, trace, interact, log_current_line


# Phase 1: The Feelings in Tweets

def make_tweet(text, time, lat, lon):
    """Return a tweet, represented as a python dictionary.

    text      -- A string; the text of the tweet, all in lowercase
    time      -- A datetime object; the time that the tweet was posted
    latitude  -- A number; the latitude of the tweet's location
    longitude -- A number; the longitude of the tweet's location

    >>> t = make_tweet("just ate lunch", datetime(2012, 9, 24, 13), 38, 74)
    >>> tweet_words(t)
    ['just', 'ate', 'lunch']
    >>> tweet_time(t)
    datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 24, 13, 0)
    >>> p = tweet_location(t)
    >>> latitude(p)
    38
    """
    return {'text': text, 'time': time, 'latitude': lat, 'longitude': lon}

def tweet_words(tweet):
    """Return a list of the words in the text of a tweet."""
    return extract_words(tweet['text'])

def tweet_time(tweet):
    """Return the datetime that represents when the tweet was posted."""
    return tweet['time']

def tweet_location(tweet):
    """Return a position (see geo.py) that represents the tweet's location."""
    return make_position(tweet['latitude'], tweet['longitude'])

def tweet_string(tweet):
    """Return a string representing the tweet."""
    return '"{0}" @ {1}'.format(tweet['text'], tweet_location(tweet))

def extract_words(text):
    """Return the words in a tweet, not including punctuation.

    >>> extract_words('anything  else.....not my job')
    ['anything', 'else', 'not', 'my', 'job']
    >>> extract_words('i love my job. #winning')
    ['i', 'love', 'my', 'job', 'winning']
    >>> extract_words('make justin # 1 by tweeting #vma #justinbieber :)')
    ['make', 'justin', 'by', 'tweeting', 'vma', 'justinbieber']
    >>> extract_words("paperclips! they're so awesome, cool, & useful!")
    ['paperclips', 'they', 're', 'so', 'awesome', 'cool', 'useful']
    """
    lst = []
    current_index = 0
    require_current_index_change = 0
    for index, character in enumerate(text): 
        if character not in ascii_letters:
            if not require_current_index_change:
                require_current_index_change = 1
                lst.append(text[current_index:index])
        elif (character in ascii_letters) and (index == len(text) - 1):
            lst.append(text[current_index:index+1])
            break
        else:
            if require_current_index_change == 1:
                current_index = index
                require_current_index_change = 0                
    return lst

def make_sentiment(value):
    """Return a sentiment, which represents a value that may not exist.

    >>> s = make_sentiment(0.2)
    >>> t = make_sentiment(None)
    >>> has_sentiment(s)
    True
    >>> has_sentiment(t)
    False
    >>> sentiment_value(s)
    0.2
    """
    assert value is None or (value >= -1 and value <= 1), 'Illegal value'
    return value

def has_sentiment(s):
    """Return whether sentiment s has a value."""
    if s == None:
        return False    
    else:
        return True

def sentiment_value(s):
    """Return the value of a sentiment s."""
    assert has_sentiment(s), 'No sentiment value'
    return s

def get_word_sentiment(word):
    """Return a sentiment representing the degree of positive or negative
    feeling in the given word, if word is not in the sentiment dictionary.

    >>> sentiment_value(get_word_sentiment('good'))
    0.875
    >>> sentiment_value(get_word_sentiment('bad'))
    -0.625
    >>> sentiment_value(get_word_sentiment('winning'))
    0.5
    >>> has_sentiment(get_word_sentiment('Berkeley'))
    False
    """
    return make_sentiment(word_sentiments.get(word, None))

def analyze_tweet_sentiment(tweet):
    """ Return a sentiment representing the degree of positive or negative
    sentiment in the given tweet, averaging over all the words in the tweet
    that have a sentiment value.

    If no words in the tweet have a sentiment value, return
    make_sentiment(None).

    >>> positive = make_tweet('i love my job. #winning', None, 0, 0)
    >>> round(sentiment_value(analyze_tweet_sentiment(positive)), 5)
    0.29167
    >>> negative = make_tweet("Thinking, 'I hate my job'", None, 0, 0)
    >>> sentiment_value(analyze_tweet_sentiment(negative))
    -0.25
    >>> no_sentiment = make_tweet("Go bears!", None, 0, 0)
    >>> has_sentiment(analyze_tweet_sentiment(no_sentiment))
    False
    """
    average = make_sentiment(None)
    words = tweet_words(tweet)
    total_sentiment = 0
    count_sentiment = 0
    for word in words:
        sentiment = get_word_sentiment(word)    
        if has_sentiment(sentiment):
            total_sentiment += sentiment_value(sentiment)
            count_sentiment += 1            
    if total_sentiment == 0:
        return average
    else:
        return total_sentiment / count_sentiment
```

As per instructions in phase 1, the solution was tested and looks fine.

Can I improve the solution code for the phase 1 assignment?

Comment: Hi, your problem seems interesting. Is there any way to hilight parts of the code that needs to be reviewed ? (There are many things that could be done differently in the code you started with but I guess there is not much point in improving that code).

Comment: @Josay there  are 11 functions defined, one need to review all except `tweet_string`

Answer (score 2):

The global design is a bit weird from my point of view but I'll comment on the code you've written.

**In `extract_words`:**

The code is properly formatted. A few remarks anyway :

- you don't need that many parenthesis.
- you don't need to check `character in ascii_letters` as it has to be true as this point.
- `require_current_index_change` looks like it should be a boolean. Just replace 1 by True, O by False and `if require_current_index_change == 1:` by `if require_current_index_change:`.
- Instead of having `require_current_index_change` to know whether you can use `current_index` or not, you could simply set `current_index` to `None` : it is easy to check and if you use the index anyway, you'll probably get an exception.
- You can get rid of the part comparing the index to the length and just handle it after the loop.
- `current_index` is probably not the best name as it let the reader think it corresponds to the index we are iterating over (aka `index`). It could be a good idea to convey the idea of beginning or starting index.

At the end, the code looks like :

```
def extract_words(text):
    lst = []
    starting_index = 0
    for index, character in enumerate(text):
        if character not in ascii_letters:
            if starting_index is not None:
                lst.append(text[starting_index:index])
            starting_index = None
        elif starting_index is None:
            starting_index = index
    if starting_index is not None:
        lst.append(text[starting_index:])
    return lst
```

Another idea would be to do things differently, by replacing unwanted characters by spaces and then to split on spaces.

**In `make_sentiment`:**

Instead of asserting, it could be an idea to raise a `ValueError`.

**In `has_sentiment`:**

You can simply : `return s is not None`.

Also, you should not compare to None using `==` but with `is` as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You'll find various tools like pep8, pyflakes, etc to check your code and detect such things.

**In `analyze_tweet_sentiment`:**

Because non-zero integers value are considered True in boolean contexts, you can write :

```
if total_sentiment:
    return total_sentiment / count_sentiment    
else:
    return average
```

Which can be written :

```
    return total_sentiment / count_sentiment if total_sentiment else average
```

Also, `average` does not need to be defined that early, it could simply be :

```
    return total_sentiment / count_sentiment if total_sentiment else make_sentiment(None)
```

Then, I am wondering if you should be checking `total_sentiment` or `count_sentiment`. This corresponds to choose whether you can have a sentiment of value 0 (for instance if you have both positive and negative words) or if it corresponds to None. This is an open question and I do not have the answer.

Finally, a slightly different way to write this function would be to abuse list comprehension in order to be able to reuse builtin functions `len` and `sum`. For instance, we'd have something like :

```
def analyse(tweet):
    sentiment_values = [sentiment_value(s) for s in (get_word_sentiment(w) for w in tweet_words(tweet)) if has_sentiment(s)]
    return sum(sentiment_values)/ len(sentiment_values) if sentiment_values else make_sentiment(None)
```